# Keep formatting using "Index Match" in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm using "INDEX MATCH" to retrieve some data from a table. The formula is the following:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Database!$A$1:$AQ$1543;MATCH($L6;Database!$A:$A;0);MATCH($A6;Database!$2:$2;0));"-")
```

When I Paste data from the source it dones't keep the original formatting. I know I could format de the data again, but the trick here is that the function function retrieves data from a dynamic function.

For instance:

Example 1:

KPI: Sales
Unit: $
The data retrieved in the database is only from Sales

Example 2:

KPI: Time spent on projects
Unit: Time
The data retrieved in the databse is only from Sales.

---

Basically I really need to keep the formatting, because I can't change the format manually considering that the KPI is always changing.

Did I explain the problem well? Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is all the text in the cell of the same format (**like this**) or does it vary (**like** _this_)?

Comment: Formulas, cannot effect formatting.  You will need vba.  Unfortunately Stack Overflow is not a place where users can put their wish list and we will churn out some code. Stack Overflow is here to help overcome specific problems with existing code. If you have code that has errors then please [edit] your question to include that code and an explanation of the error(s), so we may help you.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, the text is formatted in the same format. However, the formatting that I'm complaing is General/Currency/Date/etc... When pasted, the values are always "General", and I need for them to have the same format. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ScottCraner, I know that Stackoverflow is not a "code machine". But your response already helped me, now I know that I only can achieve what I want using a macro and not only formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using formulas. `INDEX / MATCH` will only pull the value in a cell, not any formatting.

To have dynamic formatting, you can use conditional formatting in some simpler cases, but to automatically retrieve arbitrary formatting from another cell, you'll have to use VBA code to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will work on a VBA code. Your answer didn't solve the issue but considering the data, I will consider it the right answer because it lead me to the right path